# Tensorflow python AI (tutorial by sentdex error)

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am trying 2 get a AI via the AI course by Sentdex i didnt get the install working at first, got the mac version (i am using win) then i try running the prepeare file in the setup dir and it gives me this error:

```
Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

anyone know what 2 do?

Comment: CODE: https://github.com/daniel-kukiela/nmt-chatbot the version he used in his vid

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial you're using?

Comment: @Ray https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=040CfFRJ9Rs